# Texmaker 1 2 3 buttons

Tags: texmaker

What is the usage of 1 2 3 here in the source viewer of texmaker?

[image]

Answer (score 10):

You can bookmark up to three lines in your source by clicking just left of the line number, and jump to them using those buttons. It is to ease navigation in your code.

Comment: Is there a keyboard shortcut to jump to the bookmark?

Comment: @SomJura No mention of any such shortcut at https://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/doc.html#SECTION39