# Bookmarks in texmaker

Tags: texmaker

How to add bookmark in texmaker? 
A bookmark  in the sense that mark a certain line in a certain latex file, and come back to that line later even you are opening another latex file.

The obvious different with the the question ([Texmaker 1 2 3 buttons](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134411/texmaker-1-2-3-buttons)) is that, using approach in that question, bookmarks does not persist if I close Texmaker and open the same file again.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134411/texmaker-1-2-3-buttons (for future reference, when these two questions are older and further apart).

Comment: Not duplicate IMHO, those bookmarks does not seem to persist if you close Texmaker and open the same file again.

Comment: Texmaker does highlight `% TODO`, but these comments are for some reason not listed in the structure view, as they are in TeXstudio, Kile or Latexila. There's a feature request about this here: https://code.google.com/p/texmaker/issues/detail?id=391&q=comment&colspec=ID%20Type%20Summary

Comment: Just to clarify, you are after "bookmarks" that are saved with the file, so that if you close it and reopen it later, the bookmarks will still be there?

Comment: @SeanAllred the question aren't really duplicate, as two questions are obviously different.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes, you are right, therefore the question is not really a duplicate here

Comment: @william007 Fair enough, but I'd be surprised if TeXMaker (or any other editor than *perhaps* vim/emacs) has such a function that is in any way reliable.  Perhaps a behavior for `% TODO: ` lines might be effected, though.

Answer (score 6):

Click on left side of the line no of code.

Comment: can I somehow jump to boomarks set in this way?

Answer (score 2):

I sometimes use the search function for this...

You can write a sequence of numbers and letters, e.g. "here2day", in comment at the line you want to find and search for it

Answer (score 0):

## Bookmark for the latex file in Texmaker

- From **View** check Structure to see a bookmark for various section of the document

## Bookmark for the generated PDF

- You can use the following package for generating bookmarks:
  \usepackage{bookmark}