# Is it possible to display code twice on the screen in TeXMaker?

Tags: texmaker

I want to make some large reordering of my text, wich means a lot of copy/paste work between distant chapters. I was wondering if it is possible to make TexMaker display the source viewer twice on my Screen, one next to the other, maybe instead of the Pdf viewer. Then I could have both relevant spots in my document on screen and easily copy-paste content without scrolling my finger into oblivion. It would have to be possible to scroll both sourceviewers independently.

Comment: wouldn't it be better to split the chapters in separate files and use `\include`s or `\input`s? In this way you cold open all files next to each other.

Comment: Yes they are in separate Texfiles. But fliping back and forth between windows is troublesome and I haven't found out how to display two texfiles simultaneously in a single instance of TexMaker

Comment: I only edit the main file with a TeX editor, for all others I use notepad++ (with eventual multiple sessions). Sorry that I can't help you on that specific problem.

Comment: As of texmaker 4.1.1, I don't think viewing two `tex` files side by side is available as a feature. However, there is a keyboard shortcut for cycling through the open documents; by default, on my Mac, that shortcut is Alt + Down. Moreover, *bookmarks* (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134411/texmaker-1-2-3-buttons) might come in handy for the editing you describe. You can define up to three bookmarks per open `tex` file for rapidly jumping to different parts of a file.

Comment: @Federico: Don't apologize, your comment is actually quite helpfull. If you could expand on this idea as an answer (do you use any plug-ins, what are pros und cons of using n++ instead of texeditor?) it would be realy nice:)

Comment: Wait... scrap that. The [official texmaker page](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/) shows two documents side by side. I've just never used the feature! Still, my earlier piece of advice applies.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Use the Source Viewer panel

As of texmaker 4.1.1, viewing two source files side by side, both of them in *read/write mode*, is not possible. However, texmaker allows you to open one source file in *read- only mode* in its so-called [Source Viewer panel](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/doc.html#SECTION40), precisely for easy copying & pasting between that file and other source files open in regular, read/write mode.   The screenshot below is taken from the [official texmaker page](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/doc.html#SECTION40).

[image]

To open a file in read-only mode, simply click the *Source Viewer* button (located at the bottom left of the screen), press the *Open* icon in the Source Viewer that just opened, and browse for the file in question. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c6hDE-psV4Q) shows the steps to follow.

To answer your question more specifically, nothing prevents you from having the same source file open in read/write mode (on the left) **and** in read-only mode (in the Source Viewer panel, on the right) at the same time.

### Additional tips for quick navigation

- Use the keyboard shortcut for **cycling through the open documents**; by default, on my Mac, that shortcut is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Dn</kbd>.
- Use **bookmarks** (see [Texmaker 1 2 3 buttons](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134411/texmaker-1-2-3-buttons)) to rapidly jump to different parts of a file; you can define up to three bookmarks per open `tex` file, and then access them by pressing the corresponding buttons (1,2, or 3).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, and since you asked me to expand on it, I use TeXworks only for the editing of the following files:

- the "main" file of the current document (i.e. the one that contains `\documentclass`)
- the "preamble" file, with all `includes` common to the various types of documents (articles, reports, papers)
- sometimes the `bib` file

For the remaining part, I code everything in n++ with no particular plugins, each chapter/figure/table in its own dedicated `tex` file.
If I need to compare two files I simply open two sessions of n++ side by side.

Pros of using n++:

- I am in direct control of the code (my colleagues use Lyx and I cannot stand it)
- I use n++ also for other languages, this reduces the environments in which I have to move

Cons:

- mostly, that you are in direct control of the code: if you are not a fan of coding "by hand" it can get really boring and annoying